# ClassCastException : Integer cannot be cast to Long

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Problem: When opening the game on my device, I get an error and LogCat says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:247)
        at com.lochdownstudios.projectmoney.GamePage.getDouble(GamePage.java:300)
        at com.lochdownstudios.projectmoney.GamePage.onCreate(GamePage.java:101)
```

(The line numbers obviously don't apply to this right now) I realize the problem is that something is still an Integer, but I'm confused and cannot find where/why this problem is being caused.

Code:

```
public class GamePage extends Activity {
    protected Double iMoney = 0.0;
    protected TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_page);

        money = getDouble(myPreferences, "money", iMoney);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMoney);
        tv.setText("Money: " + money);
    }

    double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) {
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));
    }
}
```

Note: all imports are included in the actual files.

Comment: can you show me the code where you put money in prefrences

Comment: are you sure you have long value in your sharedprefrences because according to error you are trying to retrieve a long value but it is an int

Comment: As the above commenters said, it looks like the value of the "money" preference is an int rather than a long. Casting would help, but you probably should first work out why you "money" is an int when you thought it was a long.

Comment: Doh! I forgot that I originally had "money" set as an integer and being stored as an integer before I changed it to a double. So I just had to reset my Shared Preferences! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the source f the class/method reported in your exception stack. Sites like grepcode can help. Line 247, SharedPreferencesImpl clearly has a hard cast on the data type (which might be an Integer) returned for the preference name "money".

```
public long More ...getLong(String key, long defValue) {
245        synchronized (this) {
246            awaitLoadedLocked();
247            Long v = (Long)mMap.get(key);
248            return v != null ? v : defValue;
249        }
250    }
```